# Calling a Remote Bean vs Local Bean in App Server

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss, ejb-3.0, application-server

Is there a noticeable amount of performance overhead in using Remote Bean Interface over using a Local Bean Interface?  I would like to have every Client application connect to remote beans if there is little performance difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is a fair amount of overhead. You'll *at least* incur serialization on every request.

Now if your requests are generally handled by one remote call that may be ok. If you're planning a lot of inter-bean communication this way I wouldn't do it that way (if you have a larger number of beans involved in creating the response to a single client request, you're going to be wasting a fair amount of time)